# Recreating a query using INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join

How can I transform this query using Inner-Join:

```
db_query("select max(field_date_and_time_value2) as last_time 
    from field_data_field_date_and_time 
    where (field_date_and_time_value2 > '".$today."') 
    AND (".$node->uid." = (select uid from node where nid = " . $node->nid ."))");
```

Comment: You just asked the same question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We're trying to build up a repository of questions and answer here that are generally useful.  It doesn't help to ask the same question more than once.

Answer (score 0):

```
from field_data_field_date_and_time fdt
JOIN node on fdt.<field> = node.uid
```

Without seeing your schema, it is hard to tell what the FK is here.